# Vue v-text directive: concatenate text from multiple variables

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to concatenate two string values into a  element, with no success thus far.  This works fine:

```
    <v-toolbar-title
      class="hidden-sm-and-down font-weight-light"
      v-text="$route.name"
    />
```

But I need to concatenate the following to $route.name somehow:
`' (' + {{sitename}} + ')'`
so that the value of local variable sitename follows the route name.

Is this possible to do in the v-text directive, or do I have to jump through hoops to assemble the string elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could do something like this:

```
v-text="`${$route.name}(${sitename})`"
```

If you'd like to read more about string concatenation in ES6 you can have a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings) article.